# Strange javascript scroll bar issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, jscrollpane

I am using the jScrollPane to add scroll bars to pages that exceed a certain height.

I can't figure out why the following page gets scroll bars even though the content is not overflowing my boundary.

Can anyone help please?

http://souk.gumpshen.com/test/contact.htm

Comment: I would guess because the margin/padding of the bottom P element pushes it over the boundary for jScrollPane without triggering a scrollable page.

Answer (score 0):

In style.css there is a class applied to the html tag

```
html{
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If I remove this style and zoom out then the scroll bars go away.  I think it depends on the zoom level of the browser.  If the user is set at a low resolution or zoomed in the contents do overflow.

Comment: I have tried removing the overflor-y and zooming out scrollbars still appear, any other ideas?